# Detectar si en dos cadenas distintas existe al menos 1 caracter igual

Tags: c#, string

Quisiera saber cómo hacer una comparación rápida entre dos cadenas para saber si comparten al menos 1 caracter en común.

**Ejemplo:**

Tengo `manzana` y  `piña`.  En este caso hay una coincidencia. La `a` está presente en ambos. Por ende, quiero que el código reconozca si hay al menos 1 coincidencia entre ambas cadenas.

Sobre este código, no sé cómo lo implementaría:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ExisteCoincidencia("manzana", "piña")); //Debería ser True
    Console.WriteLine(ExisteCoincidencia("no", "piña"));      //Debería ser False
}

private static bool ExisteCoincidencia(string s1, string s2)
{
    // ¿de qué forma podría lograrlo?
}
```

Comment: Hola Alex, bienvenido a Stackoverflow en Español. Aparentemente hay una confusión con respecto a como funciona este sitio. Te invito a que leas el [tour] para que conozcas nuestra comunidad.

Comment: Hola Alex, has de **intentarlo** tu primero y despues preguntar si tienes fallos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una forma muy sencilla y concisa de hacerlo es usando [Enumerable.Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx) para encontrar los caracteres en común, y luego combinar el resultado con [Enumerable.Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb337697(v=vs.110).aspx) para devolver `true` si hubo al menos una coincidencia.

Ejemplo:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ExisteCoincidencia("manzana", "piña"));
    Console.WriteLine(ExisteCoincidencia("no", "piña"));
}

private static bool ExisteCoincidencia(string s1, string s2)
{
    return s1.Intersect(s2).Any();
}
```

Resultado:

> True
>   False

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/BFGK43423)</kbd>

Comment: @Mariano: Aprecio el comentario y la sugerencia y estoy totalmente de acuerdo con la idea fundamental que, aunque queremos ayudar a OP con su problema específico cuando es apropiado, eso es secundario a querer compartir contenido de calidad con la comunidad en general. Mi única duda es que, si yo hubiera hecho la clase de edición que hicistes, siendo que yo mismo he respondido a la pregunta, puedo entender si mis motivos quedarían en cuestión. Tomaré en cuenta lo que me dijistes.

Comment: Muchas gracias e implementado en mi proyecto y me facilitara el proceso de comparación,gracias nuevamente.